# firefox-locale-en

Tags: firefox, software-uninstall, purge

There is a package called `firefox-locale-en` on my system (Ubuntu 20.04 lts), even though I have uninstalled Firefox on the very first day. Is it safe to purge it with `sudo apt purge firefox-locale-en`?

**EDIT 1**

If yes, what does it do?

**EDIT 2**

Even though it might sound like a silly doubt, but I would always like to have a knowledgeable person's opinion, because I remember last time python3.6 was not used by me specifically and I decided to purge it. Only to find out my PC doesn't work at all any more. And Hence I got to 20.04 from 18.04. Same way I thought firefox might be associated with some internet related service on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can remove it.

Comment: what does it do anyway?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. It is English localization for FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A locale is a "set of parameters that defines the user's language, region and any special variant preferences that the user wants to see in their user interface -- usually a locale identifier consists of at least a language identifier and a region identifier." (Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale))

It is safe to remove the `firefox-locale-en` package because since you aren't using Firefox you have no use for firefox's locale.